# Dont drop non present indexes on group_by - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get counts of specific indexes. This is currently been done using an group_by and then size. The only problem is that this approach does not return 0 for non present indexes. We actually need this information. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

When calculating it as follows:

```
counts = brands.groupby('categories').size()
```

Returns:

```
          count
category
A             4
```

I need it to return:

```
         count
category 
A            4
B            0
C            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex with the complete list of categories after the groupby:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["A"], ["A"], ["A"]], columns=["category"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  category
0        A
1        A
2        A

In [13]: res = df.groupby("category").size()

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
category
A    3
dtype: int64
```

You have to use `fill_value` to ensure it 0s the missing values:

```
In [15]: res.reindex(["A", "B", "C"], fill_value=0)
Out[15]:
category
A    3
B    0
C    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: how would the above solution be extended to handle a multi index ? Can you pass a 2d array to reindex ? Thanks in advance your answer has already been really helpful

Comment: You have to pass either a MI or an array of tuples (I don't think a plain array will cut it) see `MultiIndex.from_arrays` or `MultiIndex.from_product` (you *may* have to splat the array...).